# Retrieve data value in CGridView by relation HAS_ONE

Tags: yii

The Relation:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'submissionStatus' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'SubmissionStatus', 'submission_status_id'),
    );
}
```

Column value in GridView:

```
'value' => '$data->submissionStatus->submission_status_name',
```

SubmissionStatus Model Attributes:

```
public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'submission_status_id'   => 'Status ID',
        'submission_status_name' => 'Status Name',
    );
}
```

SubmissionStatus Relations:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'submissionStatus' => array( self::BELONGS_TO, 'Submission', 'submission_status_id' ),
    );
}
```

Yet I get an error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Why can I not retrieve `submission_status_name` by this relation?

**EDIT:**

This on the other hand works perfectly:

```
'submissionStatus' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'SubmissionStatus', 'submission_status')
```

DATABASE:

```
| tbl_submission                  |
-----------------------------------
| submission_id (int) PK          |
| submission_name (varchar)       |
| submission_status_id (int) FK   | 


| tbl_submission_status            |
------------------------------------
| submission_status_id (int) PK    |
| submission_status_name (varchar) |
```

Comment: How do you want to get `submission_status_name`? and where?

Comment: in gridview, as the value for one of the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There to 2 questions here.

1. if your relations really works
2. hot to get the data in gridview

I think you have an error in the realtion. The difference between BELONGS_TO and HAS_ONE is, that it tries to create the realtion in a different way. Could you post your Database tables, what fields they have, we need to see what is the key and foreign jey fields.
i guess it is `id` in one table and `submission_status_id` in the other one.
try to change you relation in one of these two (try if one of them works):

1.

`'submissionStatus' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'SubmissionStatus', array('submission_status_id'=>'id'),`

`'submissionStatus' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'SubmissionStatus', array('id'=>''),`

2.

in your grid the code you use is correct but as stated in the comment from @Manquer, if the relation returns null it will not work.
But you can try the more Yii style in the GridViiew like this:
do not give any `value` only tne `name`

`'name'=>'>submissionStatus.submission_status_name'`

Comment: added database structure

Answer (score 0):

If the value of relation field is null then you relation will not return a object of the Foreign model; therefore calling the attribute in it will give the error 
try changing

```
'value' => '$data->submissionStatus->submission_status_name',
```

to

```
'value' => '(isset($data->submissionStatus))?
            $data->submissionStatus->submission_status_name:""',
```